# Cannot save file with either nano or sublime text

Tags: dell, sudo, xps, nano

I am following these instructions verbatim

http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln308123/how-to-configure-the-keyboard-backlight-time-out-interval-in-ubuntu-linux?lang=en

I open the file using sudo, with either nano or sublime text as my text editor. I modify the file from 0s to 100s, and then save, but then when I reopen the file, it's always back to 0s...wtf.

Anybody know why that might happen?

Comment: I went all out and just did `sudo chmod 777 <file>` and still cannot modify it

Comment: I event logged in as root with `sudo su` and still cannot modify the file

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, if you read the article it says:

> NOTE: If AC power is plugged in you will always see 0s in the file,
>   however, it will keep the same setting for both on AC power and on
>   battery power

D'OH!

so I unplugged my computer, then modified the value, and the modifications actually showed up, so that's good. Then I plugged in my computer again and it went back to 0s. So all makes sense now...